# Count number of occurrences in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with the following structure:

```
(table_name, column_name)
```

and for each row in this table I need to query the column_name in the table_name and do a `COUNT(column_name) GROUP BY column_name` of the values in there.

Currently I do

```
SELECT * FROM this table 
/*and then*/ foreach row: do another query with: 
  SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name) GROUP BY column_name
```

Is there any way I can do this in a single query?
Something like

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name) 
GROUP BY column_name 
FOREACH(SELECT table_name, column_name FROM my_initial_table)
```

I know the last query is not valid, it's just an example for what I am looking to to achieve if it's possible.

**LE:**

The table that tells me where to look has 2 varchar columns

Ex:

```
|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| table_name | column_name      |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
| logsa      | foo              |
|===============================|
| logsa      | bar              |
|===============================|
| testx      | baz              |
|===============================|
```

This tells me that now i have too look in columns **foo** and **bar** of table **logsa** and column **baz** of table **testx**

Every column in every table has VARCHAR as datattype and i just need to count those that are the same. that's way i was doing

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name) 
    GROUP BY column_name
```

Comment: Any particular database?

Comment: ...also, could you provide the table schema, as it's not totally clear what you're after - this might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in MySql, you can't directly use parametrized column names.
There is an indirect way of doing this using stored procedures and prepared statements.

some sloppy first-draft code...
notice the difference between backticks ` and quotes '

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE CountTables()
  BEGIN
      DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE table_name varchar(30), colunn_name varchar(30);
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT
          table_name, column_name
       FROM ColumnTable;

      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1( table_name varchar(30), column_name varchar(30), count int);

      OPEN cur1;
      START TRANSACTION;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH FROM cur1 INTO table_name, column_name;
        IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;

        SET insert_sql = CONCAT(  "INSERT INTO `t1`(`table_name`, `column_name`, `count`) SELECT ",
                                   "'", table_name, "', '", column_name, "', count(`", column_name, "`)",
                                  " FROM `",    table_name, "`"  
                               );

        PREPARE insert_stmt FROM insert_sql;
        EXECUTE insert_stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE insert_stmt;

      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
      SELECT * FROM t1 GROUP BY column_name;
      DROP TEMPORARY TABLE t1;

    END;
```

Oh ya, don't forget to call the procedure:

```
CALL CountTables();
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery should be able to help you here. This is an example (untested) which should work with some refinement. I am going to call your table **Schema** for the purposes of my example, and in the subquery I am going to alias it as **ColumnCount** to make the code (hopefully) more readable.

```
SELECT Schema.table_name, Schema.column_name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Schema ColumnCount 
  WHERE Schema.column_name = ColumnCount.column_name) AS ColumnUsageCount
FROM Schema
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do a subselect, just do this, if there's only one table involved.

```
SELECT max(table_name) as table_name, column_name, COUNT(*) as occurrence
FROM initial_table
GROUP BY column_name 
ORDER BY column_name
```

The `Max(table_name)` substitutes for the non-existent function `Whatever(table_name)`.
In MySQL you can also use `group_concat(table_name) as table_names`. Try it out!

The `ORDER BY` is optional (and in MySQL not needed) but can be handy if you want it sorted by column name as well.

If you want to list the unique occurrences of the combi table_name + column_name do:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, COUNT(*) as occurrence
FROM initial_table
GROUP BY table_name, column_name 
ORDER BY table_name, column_name
```

Comment: This would work if he weren't also wanting the table_name column returned - in which case it would have to be added to the GROUP BY clause and this would return the number of occurrences per table, not over the whole dataset.

Comment: @Bork, fixed the answer to include both options.

Comment: I don't need to do the count on the initial table. The initial table only give me a list of tables and columns that i need to loop through tem all and that at the end get the number of occurrences

Comment: Better - but if the same column name is used in more than one table, there will be a single row returned with the table that is last alphabetically, instead of a row for each occurrence in each table. This will not duplicate the result the user is currently getting by doing a "SELECT *" from the table then doing individual queries to get total usage count of a column name.

Answer (score -1):

in PHP

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM $table_name");
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

I'm not too familiar with mysql, but i think its along those lines